# Jira JQL card color

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I am trying to set card colors to a specific color if the card was not updated in the last 2 days. To do so I used the following query:

```
updatedDate >= 2d
```

This does not seem to work, any ideas why?

Comment: I think that might be 2 days in the future, try -2d.

Comment: That will highlight the cards that were updated on the past 2 days which was not what i wanted. 
I changed it to this though updatedDate <= -2d and it worked. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Glad that worked :) @DárioBaltazar. May I know where are you placing this condition for showing it in different colors

Answer (score 1):

Think of time as seconds since 1970. Dates in the past have a lower number of seconds. -2d means 2 days ago from midnight today. So you probably want:

updatedDate <= 2d

Comment: Should change updatedDate <= 2d to updatedDate <= -2d. I tried to do this as an edit but some misguided individuals rejected it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351480/the-atlassian-tag-is-in-the-process-of-being-burninated